# Bash: Find position of character in a string under OS X

Tags: macos, bash, indexing, match

Is there any way to find a position of a first character within a string in *Bash* under *Mac OS X*?

Something like:

```
stringZ=abcABC123ABCabc                      # 6
echo `expr index "$stringZ" C12`             # C position.
```

as desribed in [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Couple of gotchas:

1. The official *index* function `expr index $string $substring` is not
   present in OS X (BSD) *match*
2. Installing gnu match (*gmatch*) does not seem to be a
   portable solution in the realm of BSD systems

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have an OS X to test, but would `echo $stringZ|grep C12 -o -b` do the trick?

Comment: $ echo "ASDfsfssdf" | grep D -o -b
0:D

Comment: Can you try without the -o? On my version of bash, on Linux, the behavior of -b is changed by -o, but from what I see of the Mac OS X man page, `grep C12 -b` might work.

Comment: `echo "ASDfsfssdf" | grep D -b
0:ASDfsfssdf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a horrible hack, and may not work for all cases.

```
tmp=${stringZ%%C12*}     # Remove the search string and everything after it
echo $(( ${#tmp} + 1 )) # Add one to the length of the remaining prefix
```

Comment: I was just going to suggest the same. `%%` should find the first occurrence.

Comment: `%%` would remove the longest occurrence; both will start with the first occurrence.

Comment: Double percent seems like the way to go. Eg. try this: `stringZ="A B=C=D=F"
tmp=${stringZ%%=*}     # Remove the search string and everything after it
echo $(( ${#tmp} + 1 )) # Add one to the length of the remaining prefix`

Comment: while single percent works like this: `+ stringZ='A B=C=D=F'
+ tmp='A B=C=D'
+ echo 8
8`

Comment: For the given application (find the index of the search string), the pattern used will always end in `*`, in which case there is no difference between `%` and `%%`.

Comment: @chepner: The only way how I was able to remember the difference between # and % was where they are on the keyboard. :-)

Comment: Oh, I remember which is prefix and which is suffix (I use the keyboard trick, too). That doesn't mean I remember exactly how each works :)

Answer (score 2):

Might be an overkill but how about this:

```
$ echo 'abcABC123ABCabc' | awk 'match($0,"C"){print RSTART}'
6
```