# Bash indexof substring after nth character

Tags: string, bash

is there a way to get indexOf of a substring after nth character in Bash, without needing to cut the original string one by one, that would be lengthy

```
              12345678901234
$ expr index 'abcdeabcdabcaa' 'c'
3
$ expr index 'abcdeabcdabcaa' 'ca'
1
```

What i want would be:

```
$ indexOf 'abcdeabcdabcaa' 'ca'
12
$ indexOfAfter 5 'abcdeabcdabcaa' 'c'
8
$ indexOfAfter 5 'abcdeabcdabcaa' 'ca'
12
$ indexOfAfter 9 'abcdeabcdabcaa' 'b'
11
$ indexOfAfter 111 'abcdeabcdabcaa' 'c'
0
```

probably there are already function on Bash to do this.. this is not a homework, just out of curiosity..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash: Find position of character in a string under OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615750/bash-find-position-of-character-in-a-string-under-os-x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

both operations implemented with `awk`

contents of file indexOf:

```
echo "$1" "$2" | awk '{print index($1,$2)}'
```

e.g.

```
 indexOf 'abcdeabcdabcaa' 'ca'
 12
```

contents of file indexOfAfter:

```
echo "$1" "$2" "$3" | \
awk '{s=substr($2,$1);posn=index(s,$3);if (posn>0) print $1+posn-1; else print 0;}'
```